# SLF4j and Logback in Application which can be embeddable

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, logback

I am using `SLF4j` and `Logback` in my application. Now I have the requirement that my application should be embedabble in other applications. This means, that the application can be used as a library in other applications. Everything works as expected except the Logger part. I just can't figure out how to completely disable `Logback` (this is because the user should bring its own logger implementation). I tried also to find information if it is possible to run `Logback` in something like a "delegation mode" to allow other `SLF4j` implementations to hook in, but I did not find anything.

Another approach would be to write a custom Classloader which gets rid of logback when the application starts, but this is very complicated (afaik it is not possible without hacks to remove loaded classes from classloader while the application is running).

Does anyone see a possibility to do this without splitting my application in different modules?

Comment: Separate the build-code step from the assemble-application step.  Logback goes in the latter.

Answer (score 0):

At compile time, you should only have slf4j-api in your classpath.

At runtime, you can choose to add logback in your runtime classpath, and slf4j will use it.

If the other application uses e.g. log4j, they need to add slf4j-log4j instead of logback, as well as slf4j-api and your module.

If they use java.util.logging, they need to add slf4j-jdk14 instead of logback.

In both cases, you might want to tell them which logging categories you use, so they can add it in their log4j or java.util.logging configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. Unfortunately I do have Logback in my classpath. I'm searching for a way to A) Remove Logback from the classpath while the application is running or B) Disable Logback so other implementations can hook in.

Comment: Your classpath is determined by the application, I would think. Can't you replace logback before the (embedding) application is started?